# Multithreaded Client

Tags: c#, multithreading, client-server

I created a client-server in C#, and everything works, and I thought of adding the ability to cancel requests that timed out, so at the server-side, each request I send starts a new Timer, and when it runs out of time, I send another request that says ABORT {MessageId}.

This is what I implemented so far, but for some reason, it won't terminate the Thread, when I debugged I saw that it finds the correct thread but doesn't terminate it.

Perhaps there is even a better way for implementing this...

```
Dictionary<int, Thread> threads = new();

private static void ReceiveResponse()
{
    //I get the message (body)
    string? response = Util.Bytes2String(body);
    if (response == null)
        return;
    
    //There is no need to create a new Thread for aborting a Thread...
    if (ShouldAbort(response))
        return;
        
    Thread thread = new(() =>
    {
        HandleCommand(response, msgId);
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
    });
    threads.Add(msgId, thread);
        
    thread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread {thread.ManagedThreadId} was created for Request No. {msgId}");
}


private static bool ShouldAbort(string command)
{
    if (!Util.IsStringValid(command))
        return false;

    if (command.StartsWith(MessageType.ABORT_TASK))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(command.Split('\t')[1], out int id))  //Get the ID of the message to abort
        {
            if (threads.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                AbortThreadAt(id);
                return true;
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't abort Request No. {id} because it doesn't exist");
            return false;
        }
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to stop the Thread.");
                return true;
        }
    }
        
    return false;
}

private static void AbortThreadAt(int i)
{
    try
    {
        Thread thread = threads[i];
        threads.Remove(i);
            
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread {thread.ManagedThreadId} for Request No. {i} was aborted");
        thread.Interrupt();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `Thread.Interrupt()` or `Thread.Abort()`. They cause mostly undefined behavior or are even unavailable from .NET 5.0 onwards. Instead, use a `CancellationToken` instead.  `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter()` can be used to cancel an operation after a certain time.

Comment: Also, `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;` at the end of a thread method is pointless. If at all, put it to the beginning.

Comment: I thought about using Tasks, but I couldn't find how to implement it, in a way that all tasks run on parallel and I can add a task to this list of running tasks

Comment: That's very similar to threads in this scenario. You can also add them to a list and manage them from there.

Comment: But if I'll do Task.WhenAll or WaitAll, I can't update the list of tasks until all of the running tasks are done

Comment: Why can't you use `Task.WhenAny()`?

Comment: but then it will quit the method after the first task will finish

Comment: You confuse me. Do you want to quit when all tasks finish or when one task finishes?

Comment: I never want to quit, each time I receive a command, it needs to execute on parallel with the other tasks, with the ability to cancel them

Comment: Then you need to wait for any task to finish, update the list and then continue waiting. If you use a CancellationToken each task that exceeds the timeout will terminate itself.

Comment: But then all the other tasks will start again without continuing from the place they stopped

Comment: No, that won't happen, if done properly. I think you need to read up on how tasks and threads work.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot